# Why does saving an empty textbox value to sessionStorage cause IE8 to crash?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, web-storage

I have created a simple example to demonstrate this.

```
<input id="search" type="text">

var input = document.getElementById('search');
window.sessionStorage.setItem('test', '');
alert(input.value === '');
window.sessionStorage.setItem('test2', input.value);
alert('complete');
```

Running this in IE8 causes the entire browser to crash when storing the `input.value` with a standard error - "Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close...".

The same occurs with localStorage.

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/exFt2/)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this too, though it took me a few minutes to figure out it was `sessionStorage` causing this and not our IE8 placeholder widget, knockout.js bindings, or modernizr. Our text box was `<input type="search" .../>` and that was not the problem either.

The weirdest thing is if you inspect the value using the IE8 debugger tools, the value is in fact an empty string. However, this seemed to fix it for me:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('test2', input.value || '');
```

... it almost seems like IE8 prefers a literal empty string instead of one nested in another object or returned from a function..?

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution was:

```
if(value)
    localStorage.setItem(name, value);
else if(localStorage.getItem(name))
    localStorage.removeItem(name);
```

I think it is the best way to use storage - not saving empty values but removing it from there.

Comment: I used Goncharov's answer in production code and it has been working without any problems. Thanks.